# Solve identity: $ ( \sin x + \sin y)^2 + \cos^2 x \cos^2y=( \sin x \sin y+1)^2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve identity: $$ ( \sin x +  \sin y)^2 +  \cos^2 x \cos^2y=( \sin x \sin y+1)^2 $$  I really have no idea how to do this. Like not even an idea to be honest ...

Comment: Expand each term

Comment: No idea ... maybe use $ \cos^2 x =1 - \sin^2 x$.

Comment: How do we *solve* an Identity??

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Hint that solved me my problem :p I am an idiot. Totally forgot my professor said switch everything to just sinus or just cousins when you have them both in an identity

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\sin x$ and $b=\sin y$. We know that $\cos^2 \alpha = 1-\sin^2\alpha$ so

\begin{eqnarray*}
 ( \sin x +  \sin y)^2 +  \cos^2 x \cos^2y &=& a^2 +2ab +b^2 +(1-a^2)(1-b^2)\\
& =& a^2+2ab+b^2+1-a^2-b^2+a^2b^2 \\
&=& a^2b^2+2ab+1\\
& =& (ab+1)^2\\
&=&( \sin x \sin y+1)^2 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(y)+2\sin(x)\sin(y)+\cos^2(x)\cos^2(y)=\sin^2(x)\sin^2(y)+1+2\sin(x)\sin(y)$$
$$\sin^2(x)(1-\sin^2(y))+\sin^2(y)+(1-\sin^2(x))\cos^2(y)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
(\sin x+\sin y)^2+\cos^2x\cos^2y
&=(\sin x+\sin y)^2+(1-\sin^2x)(1-\sin^2y)\\
&=(\sin^2x+2\sin x\sin y+\sin^2y)+(1-\sin^2x-\sin^2y+\sin^2x\sin^2y)\\
&=\sin^2x\sin^2y+2\sin x\sin y+1\\
&=(\sin x\sin y+1)^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sin x\sin y+1)^2-(\sin x+\sin y)^2=\cdots=(\sin^2x-1)(\sin^2y-1)=?$$